# Scala Seq of pair transformation

Tags: scala

I have the following requirements, and want to transform to the form I want. Given the input I want to do some converation to the output based on the id key of each class.

```
case class Day(id: Int, name: String)
case class Shift(id: Int, dayId: Int)
case class Break(id: Int, shiftId: Int)

val day1 = Day(1, "xx")
val day2 = Day(2, "xx")
val day3 = Day(3, "xx")

val shift1 = Shift(1, 1)
val shift2 = Shift(2, 1)
val shift3 = Shift(3, 2)

val break1 = Break(1, 1)
val break2 = Break(2, 3)

val input = Seq(
  ((day1, Some(shift1)), Some(break1)),
  ((day1, Some(shift2)), None),
  ((day2, Some(shift3)), Some(break2)),
  ((day3, None), None)
)

def convert(input: Seq[((Day, Option[Shift]), Option[Break])]): Seq[(Day, Seq[(Shift, Seq[Break])])] = {
  ???
}

val output = Seq(
  (day1, Seq((shift1, Seq(break1)), (shift2, Seq()))),
  (day2, Seq((shift3, Seq(break2)))),
  (day3, Seq())
)
```

Anyone has some idea the best way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case class Day(id: Int, name: String)
case class Shift(id: Int, dayId: Int)
case class Break(id: Int, shiftId: Int)

val day1 = Day(1, "xx")
val day2 = Day(2, "xx")
val day3 = Day(3, "xx")

val shift1 = Shift(1, 1)
val shift2 = Shift(2, 1)
val shift3 = Shift(3, 2)

val break1 = Break(1, 1)
val break2 = Break(2, 3)

val input = Seq(
  ((day1, Some(shift1)), Some(break1)),
  ((day1, Some(shift2)), None),
  ((day2, Some(shift3)), Some(break2)),
  ((day2, None), None)
)

def convert(input: Seq[((Day, Option[Shift]), Option[Break])]): Seq[(Day, Seq[(Shift, Seq[Break])])] = {
  input.groupBy(_._1._1).toSeq.map(d=>(d._1,d._2.groupBy(_._1._2).filter(_._1.isDefined).toSeq.map(s=>(s._1.get,s._2.flatMap(_._2)))))
}

val output = Seq(
  (day1, Seq((shift1, Seq(break1)), (shift2, Seq()))),
  (day2, Seq((shift3, Seq(break2)))),
  (day3, Seq())
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change the structure of your input to this :

```
  val input = Seq(
    (day1, Some(shift1), Some(break1)),
    (day1, Some(shift2), None),
    (day2, Some(shift3), Some(break2)),
    (day2, None, None)
  )
```

(you skip the nesting of the tuples)

then you can use this convert function below:

```
def convert(input: Seq[(Day, Option[Shift], Option[Break])]): Seq[(Day, Seq[(Shift, Seq[Break])])] = {
    val a = input.groupBy(_._1).map { case (day, gr) =>
        (day, gr.collect { case (_, Some(shift), breakOpt) =>
                (shift, breakOpt)
            }.groupBy(_._1).toSeq.map { case (shift, sq) => (shift, sq.flatMap(_._2))})
    }
    a.toSeq
}
```

The bottom line is that you just need to group twice. One time with day and another one with shift. The rest of the code is simply conversion to your desired output format.

The conversion can be made like this :

```
def flatten[A, B, C](t: ((A, B), C)) = (t._1._1, t._1._2, t._2)
```

and then:

```
convert(input.map(flatten))
```

Comment: How can I transform from my input to the input you specified?

Comment: you could also write flatten in the convert method, so it would accept proper format and do the flatten inside.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. The code is a little bit long but it works for your specific input. It can be also refactored, because two partial functions are almost the same.

```
case class Day(id: Int, name: String)

case class Shift(id: Int, dayId: Int)

case class Break(id: Int, shiftId: Int)

val day1 = Day(1, "xx")
val day2 = Day(2, "xx")
val day3 = Day(3, "xx")

val shift1 = Shift(1, 1)
val shift2 = Shift(2, 1)
val shift3 = Shift(3, 2)

val break1 = Break(1, 1)
val break2 = Break(2, 3)

val input = Seq(
  ((day1, Some(shift1)), Some(break1)),
  ((day1, Some(shift2)), None),
  ((day2, Some(shift3)), Some(break2)),
  ((day2, None), None)
)

type MyReturnType = (Day, Seq[(Shift, Seq[Break])])

def convert(input: Seq[((Day, Option[Shift]), Option[Break])]): Seq[MyReturnType] = {
  input.foldLeft(Seq[MyReturnType]()) {
    case (acc, ((day, Some(shift)), Some(break))) =>

      val findExistingDay = acc.find { case (d, _) => d == day }
      val seqWithoutDay = acc.filter { case (d, _) => d != day }


      val addNewElementIfDayExists = findExistingDay.map { case (d, seq) =>
        (d, seq :+(shift, Seq(break))) +: seqWithoutDay
      }

      val otherwiseCreateANewOne = addNewElementIfDayExists.getOrElse((day, Seq((shift, Seq(break)))) +: acc)
      otherwiseCreateANewOne

    case (acc, ((day, Some(shift)), None)) =>

      val findExistingDay = acc.find { case (d, _) => d == day }
      val seqWithoutDay = acc.filter { case (d, _) => d != day }


      val addNewElementIfDayExists = findExistingDay.map { case (d, seq) =>
        (d, seq :+(shift, Seq())) +: seqWithoutDay
      }

      val otherwiseCreateANewOne = addNewElementIfDayExists.getOrElse((day, Seq((shift, Seq()))) +: acc)
      otherwiseCreateANewOne

    case (acc, ((day, None), Some(break))) =>
      ??? //I don't know what should I do in this case, because you didn't provide an example
    case (acc, ((day, None), None)) =>
      acc
  }
}
val convertResult: Seq[MyReturnType] = convert(input)

convertResult.foreach(println)
/* result:
(Day(2,xx),List((Shift(3,2),List(Break(2,3)))))
(Day(1,xx),List((Shift(1,1),List(Break(1,1))), (Shift(2,1),List())))
res0: Unit = ()
 */

//if you need it in a specific order:

convertResult.sortBy(_._1.id).foreach(println)
/* result:
(Day(1,xx),List((Shift(1,1),List(Break(1,1))), (Shift(2,1),List())))
(Day(2,xx),List((Shift(3,2),List(Break(2,3)))))
res1: Unit = ()
 */

//if you also need an empty day3, then you have to somehow group the all days. Maybe like this::
val allDays = List(day1, day2, day3)
val withEmptyDays: Seq[MyReturnType] = allDays.map(d => convertResult.find(_._1 == d).getOrElse((d, Seq())))
withEmptyDays.foreach(println)
/*
(Day(1,xx),List((Shift(1,1),List(Break(1,1))), (Shift(2,1),List())))
(Day(2,xx),List((Shift(3,2),List(Break(2,3)))))
(Day(3,xx),List())
res2: Unit = ()
 */


val output = Seq(
  (day1, Seq((shift1, Seq(break1)), (shift2, Seq()))),
  (day2, Seq((shift3, Seq(break2)))),
  (day3, Seq())
)
```

Of course THIS IS SCALA and you can write it in a concise way:

```
 def convert(input: Seq[((Day, Option[Shift]), Option[Break])]): Seq[(Day, Seq[(Shift, Seq[Break])])] = {
   def helper(acc:Seq[(Day, Seq[(Shift, Seq[Break])])], day:Day, shift:Shift, breaks:Seq[Break]) =
     acc.find(_._1 == day).map(a =>(a._1, a._2 :+ (shift, breaks)) +: acc.filter(_._1 != day)).getOrElse((day, Seq((shift, breaks))) +: acc)
   input.foldLeft(Seq[(Day, Seq[(Shift, Seq[Break])])]()) {
     case (acc, ((day, Some(shift)), Some(break))) => helper(acc, day, shift, Seq(break))
     case (acc, ((day, Some(shift)), None)) => helper(acc, day, shift, Seq())
     case (acc, ((day, None), Some(break))) =>
       ???
     case (acc, ((day, None), None)) =>
       acc
   }
 }
```